# XCode won't update from App Store

Tags: xcode, app-store

This night I've update my iPhone which I use to test my applications but that caused a problem of "Developer Disk Image", which, as I understood, basically means that Apple wants me to update my Xcode.

However, when I try to do so from "updates" tab in App Store, after I press "update" button, it just simply goes to "waiting" and then back to no progress at all. It does not update after that and the icon of the app in Launcher becomes grey, has a progress bar below it and stays at 0bytes.

I tried to delete the app and download it from the App Store again, but it all ends with Xcode.appdownload file being downloaded and that's it. Even if I try to launch that file (I know it's dumb, but should have tried) nothing happens. How do I get my App Store to work again?

Comment: The progress bar has been quite buggy for me since Yosemite and still in Maverics... So it might be the same issue. It is still working, just not showing any progress. Have you tried just leaving it on? Or monitoring activity? You might also be able to see the progress in the finder or launchpad.

Comment: Maybe this could work for this issue. http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/153864

Comment: @VictorPurMar I've already tried this, but, unfortunately, it didn't help me.

Comment: @MartijnKooij Might be so, I was just too impatient because I did not know it is possible for the progress bar to have such a major bug, which makes its existence pointless

Comment: This isn't a programming question. Please try asking on http://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: My bad, did not know about that service @rmaddy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I solved the issue - even though it does not mention System Updates anywhere, all I had to do is to update OS first. C'mon, Apple inc. get your scheiße together, just bugging away is not an answer!

Answer (score 2):

The Mac App Store is broken beyond repair. You can try to reload the update page using CMD-R. That helps sometimes. In addition, Launchpad normally shows the progress correctly.

You can also update from Terminal.app using the command

```
softwareupdate -l
```

Good luck!

Comment: I tried to use Terminal and this is what I've got: 
`Software Update found the following new or updated software:
   * RAWCameraUpdate6.17-6.17
 Digital Camera RAW Compatibility Update (6.17), 7455K [recommended]
   * OS X El Capitan Recovery Update-1.0
 OS X El Capitan Recovery Update (1.0), 463551K [recommended]
   * iTunesX-12.3.2
 iTunes (12.3.2), 241328K [recommended]`
 In other words, it does not look like any of these is Xcode